# Clipping NetCDF files with a geodataframe in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, geo, clip, wkt

I have monthly estimates of PM 2.5 for 20 consecutive years stored in NetCDF files with a precision of 0.01°x0.01° (i.e. for each 0.01°x0.01° square on the world map, there is an estimate of PM 2.5). [The data is here for those interested.](https://sites.wustl.edu/acag/datasets/surface-pm2-5/)

I wish to clip the NetCDF files with a geodataframe containing the bounding boxes of the cities I am interested in and then make an average of the PM 2.5 for each city (as they might be in more than one 0.01°x0.01° square).

The geodataframe has the following form

```
cities    longmin    latmin    longmax    latmax    WKT

Rennes    -1.72      48.08     -1.61      48.15    POLYGON ((-1.72 48.08, -1.61 48.08, -1.61 48.15, -1.72 48.15, -1.72 48.08))

Bursa     29.01      40.17      29.15     40.23    POLYGON ((29.01 40.17, 29.15 40.17, 29.15 40.23, 29.01 40.23, 29.01 40.17))

Copenhagen12.45      55.61      12.67     55.73    POLYGON ((12.45 55.61, 12.67 55.61, 12.67 55.73, 12.45 55.73, 12.45 55.61))

...
```

I have the following code to clip the data, my problem is that it is made for points and the output file only describes Rennes. I want it do to clip the NetCDF files to only keep the squares of the cities I have the bounding boxes of in my GeoDataFrame.

```
import os, sys
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from shapely import wkt




# creating a geodataframe with the .xls file


df = pd.read_excel('/Users/lucius/Documents/MiR/Data1/bounding_boxes.xls')

print(df)



df['WKT'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['WKT'])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='WKT')

print(gdf.head())




path="/Users/lucius/Documents/MiR/Data1/"

for year in range(2020,2000,-1):
    for month in range(12,1,-1):  
        outputfile=path + 'Monthly_csv/Asia.'+str(year)+str(month)+'.csv'
        if os.path.isfile(outputfile)==False:
                fn=path+'Monthly/V5GL01.HybridPM25.Asia.'+str(year)+str(month)+'-'+str(year)+str(month)+'.nc'
                ds_temp = Dataset(fn, format="NETCDF4")
                minlon=ds_temp.variables['LON'][0].tolist()
                maxlon=ds_temp.variables['LON'][-1].tolist()
                maxlat=ds_temp.variables['LAT'][0].tolist()
                minlat=ds_temp.variables['LAT'][-1].tolist()
                bounds = gdf['geometry'].bounds
                minx=bounds['minx'].values[0]
                maxx=bounds['maxx'].values[0]
                maxy=bounds['maxy'].values[0]
                miny=bounds['miny'].values[0]
                i_min=int((minx-minlon)/.01)
                i_max=int((maxx-minlon)/.01)+1
                j_min=int((maxlat-maxy)/.01)
                j_max=int((maxlat-miny)/.01)+1
                points=[]
                i_s = []
                j_s = []
                pol = []
                co=[]
                for i in range(i_min,i_max+1):
                        for j in range(j_min,j_max+1):
                                centro_x = minlon + .01*i
                                centro_y = maxlat - .01*j
                                points.append(Point(centro_x,centro_y))
                                i_s.append(i)
                                j_s.append(j)
                                pol.append(ds_temp.variables['PM25'][j,i].data.tolist())
                pnts = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':points,'i':i_s,'j':j_s,'pol':pol})
                pnts.crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
                pnts['lon']=pnts.geometry.x
                pnts['lat']=pnts.geometry.y
                pnts_within = gpd.sjoin(pnts,gdf, how="inner", op='intersects')
                pnts_within['year']=year
                pnts_within=pnts_within[['year','pol','lon','lat']]
                pnts_within.to_csv(outputfile,mode='w',index=False)
                print("-> "+str(year)+" done.")
        else:
                print(str(year) +'already done')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am a beginner in Python and I can't seem to find answers elsewhere.

Comment: Check out [regionmask](https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.0/index.html) - it’s designed for this exact problem!

Comment: And definitely check out xarray. It’ll make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: How can I build a region for each of the city I have in the .csv file? I also can't figure if I lose any information after importing the NetCDF file in an xarray, do I need to do anything after ```ds_temp2 = xarray.open_dataset('path/to/file/*.nc')
df = ds_temp2.to_dataframe()```

Comment: I wouldn’t convert it to a dataframe. Look at the regionmask tutorials - you should be able to directly work with the xarray DaraArrays.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Delgado. I found some help using this [page](https://www.guillaumedueymes.com/post/shapefiles_country/) I am now waiting for the mask to be applied to the xarray of the NetCDF which seems to take a lot of time (more than 45 mins for now). Do you know anything I could do that could speed up the process ? I have 200 files to clip.